# C# Elvis Operator nullable boolean

Tags: c#, .net, boolean, operators

How can I apply to Elvis Operator to the following:

```
Exp: b= a?.attr> 0
```

The outcome should be: if `a` is `null`, `b` should be `null`, otherwise, `b` should be the result of `attr > 0`.

Comment: Can you add some examples please, its hard to know what you mean

Comment: _" if boolean `a` ..."_ If `a` is a `bool`, how can it have a property `attr`?

Comment: So left me see if I understand: `b` is a nullable bool, and you want it to be null if `a` is null, true if `a.attr > 0`, or false if `a.attr <= 0`?

Comment: This question is a little bit confusing; can you write out a short, like around ten line **complete program that we can run** that shows what you mean?

Comment: It would be great if you would at least show the declaration and initialization of `a`. Is it correct that `b` is a `Nullable<bool>`?

Comment: If you want to check `a` for `null`, you can try `bool? b = a == null ? (bool?) null : a.attr > 0;` and you'll get `null` if `a` is `null` and `true` or `false` when `a` is not `null`

Comment: `bool? b = a?.attr == null ? null : a?.attr > 0 ? true : false`, this shall help, checks null, then assign value as true or false

Answer (score 6):

As others noted in now-deleted answers, the problem you are having is because of a questionable design decision. A "lifted" operator is a version of a normal operator that takes nullables, produces null if an operand is null and produces a nullable version of the regular operator otherwise. For example, addition is a lifted operator:

```
int? a = 111;
int? b = null;
int? c = a + a; // 222, but nullable
int? d = a + b; // null
```

The problem you are running into is that *comparison operators in C# do not follow the pattern of the other lifted operators*.  In C#, comparison operators are:

- `==` produces true if both operands are null, false if exactly one operand is null, and otherwise does non-lifted equality
- `!=` does the opposite of `==`
- `<`, `>`, `<=` and `>=` produce false if either operand is null, and otherwise do regular comparison. Note that this means that `x == y` can be true and `x >= y` can be false, which means that `>=` does not have the same meaning as "greater than OR equal".

It is a mess and you are right to be confused by it.

What you might do is just write a method that has the semantics you want:

```
static bool? LiftedLessThan(int? x, int? y) => 
  (x == null | y == null) ? (bool?)null : x.Value < y.Value;
```

(Note that the cast is required to keep the C# type system happy, which requires that both the consequence and the alternative of a conditional have a consistent type.)

And now your program fragment is:

```
bool? b = LiftedLessThan(a?.attr, 0);
```

It's not as nice to look at, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want the following in a oneliner with [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) :

```
if(A==null){
    B=null;
}
else{
    B= A.Attr > 0
}
```

You can simply assign B to null by default:

```
bool? B = null;
if(A==null){
    B= A.Attr > 0
}
```

or as Dmitry Bychenko commented:

```
 B = a == null ? (bool?)null : a.Attr > 0;
```

May you confirm that you expected result are :

> A  is not null, A.Attr = 0 => B= False
>   A  is not null, A.Attr = 2 => B= True
>   A  is not null, A.Attr = -1 => B= False
>   A  is null, A.Attr = is null => B= is null

```
public class A { public int Attr; }
private static void SO_52969048()
{
    bool? B ;
    var inputs = new List<A> {
        new A{ Attr = 0},
        new A{ Attr = 2},
        new A{ Attr = -1},
        null
    };

    foreach (var a in inputs)
    {
        B = a == null ? (bool?)null : a.Attr > 0;
        Console.WriteLine($" A  {(a == null ? "is null" : "is not null")}, A.Attr = {(a == null ? "is null" : a.Attr.ToString())} => B= {(B == null ? "is null" : B.ToString())}");
    }
}
```